# CSS Same Height As Other Div?

Tags: css, html, web

I have a website I am developing.
I have this div with another div inside of it named 'second'.
I want the first div to be the same height as 'second'.
So I make the `height:` of the first div: `height:auto;` but that doesnt work, that makes it shorter then 'second'. How do I set the height of the first div to match the 'second' div?
The reason why the height needs to be  the same as 'second'is because 'second' has expanding content in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some reasons the outer div doesn't span as the inner does.

1. `.second` is floated. If that's that case add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` just before the outer div is closed.
2. `.second` is absolutely positioned. There's no way to resolve that issue.

Comment: You could also set `.first` to `overflow: auto` instead of doing the first option.

Comment: As Wex said, use overflow or a clearfix instead of a meaningless div.

Comment: I would recommend using a tried and true clearfix instead of adding an extra div (I prefer [the micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), although I use the class `.clear` instead of `.cf`), but for the moment, this will work.  +1

Answer (score -1):

Try setting padding to 0 and margin to 0 as well.
You can ignore the height.

this code below worked for me.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<div style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
<div style="border:1px solid #000;height:100px;">
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```